# Using iOS 6 Event kit to work with reminders

Tags: xcode, macos

Hello Guys I'm trying to make a reminder app for my iPhone for school and i keep having this errors that I don't know what is causing can anyone here help me with these errors?

(http://prntscr.com/7u0hh6)
[image]

Comment: You should post some example code ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Include what you've already tried and where exactly you're stuck. See more info at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks!

Comment: Do not show pictures of code. Show _code_.

Answer (score 0):

EKEventStore is a class. You are trying to compare a class to nil, which makes no sense. It also looks like you have not declared _eventStore.